# Fulltext search, Bypassing word length & stop words? No access to config file

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I am using fulltext searching to avoid `WHERE column LIKE '%keyword%'` and it's disadvantages.  However, I have run into a problem with minimum word length setting (client's server is set to 4) and certain stop words.  However, my client's server does not give me access to MySQL config.  Is it possible to bypass word length and/or stop words somehow in my SQL statements?

Comment: No.  These are global server variables that affect the way the index is constructed.

Comment: No, you cannot change them from within mysql. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html   note the "ft_whatever" settings. they're not "dynamic", meaning they're set at startup time via .ini directives, and cannot be overriden.

Comment: So in this case, I am stuck with `WHERE column LIKE '%keyword%'` style search?